# May an A330 depart with with empty outer fuel tanks?

Tags: fuel-systems, fuel-tanks, airbus-a330

Airbus does not recommend flying with empty outer tanks, to reduce stress on the wings. Also, when the outer tank transfer valve is inoperative, the MEL says to fill the outer tanks with fuel and it will all be unusable during flight.

Otherwise, I couldn't find a specific restriction anywhere about departing with empty outer tanks. Is it acceptable or not?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of answers you are looking for? You already know what Airbus think about this issue, and why.

Comment: Don't know the system at all, but it sounds like if you fill inner tanks only, the xfer system will automatically move fuel to the outer tanks to move the fuel mass outboard, but if inop it can't do this so you have to fill them for ballast.  If it was that big  a deal, there must be an Operating Limitation in the AFM.

Comment: @DeepSpace some answer that I couldn't find out. I read it as a recommendation but thinking about MEL, maybe it is mandatory

Comment: @John K there is no such automatic system . thanks

Comment: The MMEL instruction is mandatory if you want to dispatch using that relief (I'm assuming it says "fill the outer tanks", not "recommended to fill the outer tanks"), but where the instruction has to be followed as opposed to recommended, I would've expected to find an Operating Limitation associated with it.